# Delphi TypeInfo for generic records

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010, rtti, typeinfo

I'm trying to use generic records with RTTI, but ran into a problem with Type Info. Does anyone know why the following won't compile using Delphi 2010?

```
program GenericTypeInfo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  TypInfo,
  SysUtils;

type

  TMyRec<T> = record
  public
    Value: T;
  end;

  TMyInt = TMyRec<Integer>;
  TMyString = TMyRec<String>;

begin

  try
    Writeln(GetTypeName(TypeInfo(TMyRec<Integer>)));     <--- This works fine
    Writeln(GetTypeName(TypeInfo(TMyRec<String>)));      <---   so does this
    Writeln(GetTypeName(TypeInfo(TMyInt)));              <--- BUT this won't compile
    Writeln(GetTypeName(TypeInfo(TMyString)));           <---   nor this!!
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

  Readln;

end.
```

The lines indicated above generate the following compiler errors:

```
[DCC Error] GenericTypeInfo.dpr(24): E2134 Type 'TMyInt' has no type info
[DCC Error] GenericTypeInfo.dpr(24): E2134 Type 'TMyString' has no type info
```

I can't what's the big difference between the 2? I admit I'm not a low-level expert, but why does the compiler treat this differently? I need it to work for the TMyInt and TMyString types.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the compiler report an error

Comment: Yes of course sorry I should've included this in my post: [DCC Error] GenericTypeInfo.dpr(24): E2134 Type 'TMyInt' has no type info

Comment: When it comes to Generics, RTTI generation is still not 100% complete yet.

Comment: Does "not 100% complete" means that there is no workaround available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [bug in Delphi 2010](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78112) which has been fixed for XE and higher.

But there is a [workaround](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=270).

Comment: +1 As far as I understand, the workaround allows to compile, but sadly there is still no type information available (the method returns nil)...

Comment: The workaround is valid thank you but I'm now running into a runtime type cast issue with RTTI. The above workaround returns TypeInfo for TMyRec<String> which it seems cannot be assigned to a TMyString property using RTTI & TValue.Make. Any ideas? Or should I post another question.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez The article says that might be the case but infact it returns a valid TypeInfo in this particular case. I guess the typeinfo/RTTI is missing for that property as the TypeInfo should be compatible (as it is exactly the same as TMyString *is* TMyRec<string>)

Comment: @RickWheeler Better to open a new question and post your code that does not work now.

Answer (score 3):

This example works fine in XE2. (And XE as @StefanGlienke comments).

RTTI and generics in Delphi-2010 lacks implementation in many ways.

Since the interpretation of types is done by compiler magic, the workaround is to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the info and could be a case for upgrading, but would prefer exploring other solutions before spending money AND spending a lot of time upgrading other libraries and so forth.